# Taking and sharing handle control of file

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a software service running and monitoring a directory containing files of assorted images. Is there any way (APIs) in Windows that I can use to get (open/read from and write to) the files in there without having to turn off the process that is gnawing them ? I want to do this with C++.

Comment: Pick one OS. The problem you're describing is improbable outside Windows.

Comment: Let's make this in Windows first. But if you happen to see somewhere posts asking about this in Linux and Mac, you can think it's me, even though I do hope if you could offer ideas for all threes.

Comment: Windows I/O has a shared-access model. Don't confuse this with file locking, which is a separate system. When a device, file or directory is opened via `CreateFile` (or low-level `NtOpenFile` or `NtCreateFile`), the request has to specify whether read/execute, write/append, and delete access should be shared. If the requested access and sharing are incompatible with existing references, then the open request fails as a sharing violation.

Comment: Note that the sharing mode is checked whenever a new kernel File object is created. If for some reason you can't resolve the sharing mode to work cooperatively in your scenario, then you can devise an IPC mechanism (e.g. using a named pipe or socket) to have the service duplicate the File handles into the requesting process.